# Phonegap Build with Childbrowser causes App Crash on IOS

Tags: ios, cordova, build, childbrowser, crash

I am Using Phonegap 2.5.0 with JQuery Mobile and the latest ChildBrowser Plugin. When i start a Build on Phonegap, after installing the App on the Device and calling the ChildBrwoser may causes an App Crash on IOS by forced closing the App in the first second. After about 5 Builds (Upload and Build) it works without any Problems??

IOS 6.1.4 (10B350) on IPhone 5.2
Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Crashed Tread: 0 (com.apple.main-thread)

Does anyone else have this Problem?

Comment: It seems that the app Crash is caused by fireing the ChildBrowser.showWebPage twice within few milliseconds. i have added a Counter for preventing a second call to this procedure which works fine, for now...

Comment: Could you post your fix here as an answer? I'm sure many could benefit from it.